# how to activation the nav tabs in rails using jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu which has a `ul` like:

```
<ul class="tabs pull-right">
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li class="active"><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
  <% else %>    
  <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <% end %>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li><a href="/upgrade">Upgrade</a></li>
  <% else %>
  <li><a href="/pricing">Pricing</a></li>
  <% end %>
```

**My jquery code is**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tabs li").click(function() {
    $(".tabs li").removeClass('active');

    var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(selected_tab).fadeIn();
    return false;
  });
});
```

**My css**

```
.tabs_wrapper { width: 900px; } 
.tabs_container { border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc; } 
.tabs { list-style: none; padding: 5px 0 4px 0; margin: 0 0 0 10px; font: 1.15em arial; } 
.tabs li { display: inline; } 
.tabs li a { border: 1px solid #ccc; 
             padding: 4px 6px; text-decoration: none; 
             background-color: #eeeeee; border-bottom: none; 
             outline: none; border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0; -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0; 
             -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px; 
             -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px; } 
.tabs li a:hover { background-color: #dddddd; padding: 4px 6px; } 
.tabs li.active a { border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; background-color: #fff; padding: 4px 6px 5px 6px; border-bottom: none; } 
.tabs li.active a:hover { background-color: #eeeeee; padding: 4px 6px 5px 6px; border-bottom: none; }
```

My problem is when I try to click pricing, the page is activating but in menu it is showing home...it is not activating the pricing tab in menu .... can any one of u tell what's the problem?

Comment: this requires the information about your css and menu code.

Comment: .tabs_wrapper {
    width: 900px;
}
.tabs_container {
    border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc;
}
.tabs {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 0 4px 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    font: 1.15em arial;
}
.tabs li {
    display: inline;
}
.tabs li a {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-bottom: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

Comment: .tabs li a:hover {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    padding: 4px 6px;
}
.tabs li.active a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 4px 6px 5px 6px;
    border-bottom: none;
}
.tabs li.active a:hover {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    padding: 4px 6px 5px 6px;
    border-bottom: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery Code doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

here is the code as far as I understand it

1. bind a click event to all tab elements
2. remove "active" class from all tab elements
3. get the "href" attribute value of the tab you clicked
4. Add an active class to the tab you clicked
5. This next part $(selected_tab) part should give you an error the
   href value you pulled out shouldnt able to be transformed into a
   jQuery object afaik.

Please provide some more info as to what you are trying to do.

From what I can tell clicking on a tab gives you a hard page refresh loading the page in the href attribute not referencing a DOM element on the same page. If that is the case the code you have above will never set the active tab because once you click you are navigating away.

based on the little info I have you could do something like this but it wouldnt be ideal would flicker most likely.

```
$(function() {
  // cache your tabs selector
  var $tabs = $('.tabs li');

  // see what page you are currently on to compare to tabs
  var pageLocation = window.location.pathname;

  // remove the Active class from the tabs
  $tabs.removeClass('active');

  // loop through your tabs
  $tabs.each(function () {
    var $tab = $(this);
    var tabHref = $tab.attr('href');

    if (tabHref === pageLocation){
      $tab.addClass('active');
    }
  });

  // Alternative dont add active to any tabs in your template and select by href
  // this selector would be slow
  $('a[href="'+pageLocation+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/billpull/D3jKZ/

Like I said before this would not be ideal. This is most likely something you would want to set in your template not too familiar with RoR/erb templating but I would think you could do something where you have a base template setup with the tabs and then you have a loop that runs through them and checks the active page. Here is an example in jinja for python

Base.html

```
{% set logged_in_tabs = [
   ('/dashboard', 'dashboard', 'Dashboad'),
   ('/upgrade', 'upgrade', 'Upgrade')
] %}

{% set unauthed_tabs = [
   ('/', 'home', 'Homepage'),
   ('/pricing', 'pricing', 'Pricing')
] %}

{% set active_page = active_page|default("home") %}

<ul class="tabs">
  {% if user_signed_in %}
    {% for href, id, caption in logged_in_tabs %}
       <li {% if id == active_page %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ href|e }}">{{ caption|e }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
       {% for href, id, caption in unauthed_tabs %}
         <li {% if id == active_page %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ href|e }}">{{ caption|e }}</a></li>
       {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
</ul>
```

Dashboard.html

```
{% extends 'Base.html' %}
{% set active_page = 'dashboard' %}
```

You will have to find someway to convert that to erb if possible. It sounds like your tabs are common elements anyways so they should be a partial or part of a master template that gets extended by dashboard, upgrade, etc. This approach will keep the work of highlighting tabs off the client side and prevent any sort of flickering that might happen on page load.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.BillPull but i fix this problem using title name.

Comment: can you add an answer so other people can see how you fixed the problem.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selected_tab = $(document).attr('title');
    $('#' + selected_tab).addClass("active");//.fadeIn();
});
</script>
<div class="masthead">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <li id="Dashboard"><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
    <% else %>    
    <li id="Home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <% end %>
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <li id="Upgrade"><a href="/upgrade">Upgrade</a></li>
    <% else %>
    <li id="Pricing"><a href="/pricing">Pricing</a></li>
    <% end %>

Comment: Mr. BillPull Can u suggest me to fix this problem in another way if possible........Thanks.

Comment: the code above should work if you have the title match the id of the tag exactly. make sure they match in your inspector/console do something like $(document).attr('title') === $('#dashboard').attr('id');

Comment: it could be possible that you need to trim whitespace or do a toLower. Also I think you could combine your if else to   <% if user_signed_in? %> 
   <li id="Dashboard"><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
   <li id="Upgrade"><a href="/upgrade">Upgrade</a></li> 
  <% else %> 
   <li id="Home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
   <li id="Pricing"><a href="/pricing">Pricing</a></li> 
  <% end %>